# Selenium / getElements By XPATH and CONTAINS (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, contains, element

I have a list of dynamic links with also dynamic `IDs`, `CSS` and all other options to get a list of elements are not useful expect one way. Using `contains()`. But in which way?

The list contains `XPATH` values like this:

```
//a[@id='contentDataTable:4711:startMenu']/span
//a[@id='contentDataTable:4712:startMenu']/span
//a[@id='contentDataTable:4713:startMenu']/span
..
//a[@id='contentDataTable:4714:startMenu']/span
```

Matches I can't use, because of the `XPATH 1.0` support only with Selenium. So I am searching for the correct `contains()` call...

A first idea was

```
xpath=//a[contains(@id, 'contentDataTable:')]
```

but it don't work.

How I've tried to get elements:

```
public List<WebElement> getWebElements(Boolean isDebug, Boolean isHPOMDebug, RemoteWebDriver remWebDriver, String htmlType, String htmlValue, String actField) {
    List<WebElement> webElements = null;
    String           webRequest  = "";

    try {
        switch (htmlType) {
            case "XPATH":
                webRequest  = htmlValue;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.xpath(webRequest));
                break;

            case "LINKTEXT":
                webRequest  = htmlValue;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.linkText(webRequest));
                break;

            case "LINKTEXTPART":
                webRequest  = htmlValue;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.partialLinkText(webRequest));
                break;

            case "CSS":
                webRequest  = htmlValue;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(webRequest));
                break;

            case "TAG":
                webRequest  = htmlValue;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.tagName(webRequest));
                break;

            case "ID":
                webRequest  = actField;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.id(webRequest));
                break;

            case "NAME":
                webRequest  = actField;
                webElements = remWebDriver.findElements(By.name(webRequest));
            break;


            default:
                webElements = null;
        } // END OF INNER SWTICH

        if (isDebug && webElements != null && webElements.size() > 1) {
            logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "getWebElements: " + webRequest + " FOUND: " + webElements.size());
            for (int i=0;i<webElements.size(); i++) {
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "getWebElements: (" + i + ") TEXT = [" + webElements.get(i).getText()     + "]");
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "getWebElements: (" + i + ") TAG  = [" + webElements.get(i).getTagName()  + "]");
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "getWebElements: (" + i + ") LOC  = [" + webElements.get(i).getLocation() + "]");
            }
            report.flush();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        webElements = null;
    }

    return(webElements);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? it or `//a[starts-with(@id, 'contentDataTable:')]` should work.

Comment: Your provided xpath looks ok so Why this xPath doesn't work?? Is there any exception??

Comment: your xpath looks okej, have tested it directly in firefox or chome with your xpath?

Comment: @splash58

I got an null pointer exception...

I check this again, perhaps I am an idot :)

Comment: Does `//a[@id='contentDataTable:4713:startMenu']/span` return a result?

Comment: This one works... and no, I am not an idiot...

Comment: Could you share your Java code as well?? I want to see how you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Use any selector that works, if you check the selector manually in the browser and it works it should be ok. One thing you need to check is that you wait for that element in case you have a page load. If you cannot identify the element please provide the html section with the menu else please provide the code you are using, maybe there is a coding issue.

Comment: @splash58

The starts-with works for general, but it founds also to much... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your `xpath` is correct and your Java code for the method `getWebElements(Boolean isDebug, Boolean isHPOMDebug, RemoteWebDriver remWebDriver, String htmlType, String htmlValue, String actField)` to getting elements also looks ok.

Line which you commented out :-

> I got an null pointer exception... I check this again, perhaps I am an idot

You're getting `NullPointerException` because you're initialising very first `webElements` variable as `null` which is wrong.

You should change this line :-

```
List<WebElement> webElements = null;
```

To

```
List<WebElement> webElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

Comment: I think you are wrong. The null pointer happens only(!!!) by working with contains. The method is always the same as you see above.

Comment: @OldMan No, FYI `findElements` never returns `null`, it returns either list of WebElement or empty list, so most probably this is the cause of null pointer, you need to change that line as suggested..

Comment: Because this make no sense as `null = list`, it would always throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Well, it also produce an exception, And if I have an exception, I set the return value to null; I guess this is the point the null pointer exception later... I check this currently... ;) and maybe I am an idiot in this detail...

Comment: So could you provide original exception which you are catching instead??

Comment: Yes, that's the point with the null pointer exception... it happens later, if the return value is "empty".

Comment: [java] org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression xpath=//a[contains(@id, 'contentDataTable')] because of the following error:
     [java] TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
     [java]   (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.87)
     [java]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktr...

Comment: No - please no chat. FFrom my point of view, I am on the right track, I think. So we could end the discussion here with no chat.

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy to get a css selector for this.
Css should work ok is you are using one of the following selectors:

```css
a[id*=contentDataTable][id*=startMenu]
a[id*=contentDataTable]
```

What this selector does is:
- finds `<a>` element that has an id that contains contentDataTable
- for the same element we can add another condition that the id should also contain startMenu

If we use a space, for example: div a[id*=contentDataTable] will mean to find an element `<a>` that has an id which contains contentDataTable, but this element should be inside the div.

Another thing you could do is to remove the ":" from your xpath and see if this is the issue of the error.

Css selectors are very well explained on w3schools, you will see there a table with few basic selector, you should read them to understand better.

Please check [w3schools css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: No, you can use css to identify almost any element, if you check the link i gave you will see that you could select most of the elements using id,class,tags and any other attribute.

Comment: The first option found none, the last to much - but it seems to be a way...

Comment: You need to narrow the section where it looks for the link or add more restrictions. For example a[id*=contentDataTable].myClass would mean that the element a should also have the class myClass

Comment: That is the problem fro real. The only difference of all elements is...

     //a[@id='contentDataTable:4711:startMenu']/span
     //a[@id='contentDataTable:4712:startMenu']/span

...the value between in the :. All other parts are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not getting the elements you need, then probably there are some other elements on the page that fits the xpath. You can improve your xpath like;

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id, 'contentDataTable') and contains(@id, 'startMenu')]"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, too. It helps to find the right contains logic.